# How to add padding to title in `matplotlib.animation`?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I created an animation using python `matplotlib.animation` library and I'm quite happy with it. The output is
[image]

The only part I'm unhappy with is the title. As you can see it "jiggles" around. The update function in the animation looks like this

```
def update_curves(num):
    # do stuff with data to get lines
    title.set_text('September 5th, 1994 at 00:00h\n + {}y {}d'.format(int(time[num]/365),int(time[num]%365)))
    return title, lines
```

Is there a way to stop the `y` and `d` from moving around?

I tried searching SO for info on how padding might work but I haven't really seen something that is compatible with `matplotlib.animation`. Using tabs also doesn't work since they don't get displayed properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using good old string formatting:

```
title.set_text('September 5th, 1994 at 00:00h\n + {:3}y {:5}d'.format(int(i), int(i*20)))
title.set_family("monospace")
```

`{:3}` formats the string so that it is exactly 3 characters long, and is left padded with spaces.

If you use the normal serif/sans-serif font, you will still have some jitter since each digit/letter is not equal in width, but set the font family to `monospace` and it works correctly.

Comment: Worked! `ax.set_title` has no option to set the font-family, but you can just use `plt.rcParams.update({"font.family": "monospace"})` (which changes the setting for the entire file, but that is fine with me.)

Comment: Oh! I missed that. I was using `ax.set_title` and then switched to `title.set_text` without checking! I will update the answer for correctness